# How to slice pandas' dataframe / series into hours blocks based on index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I would like to save plots of 6h blocks from a dataframe containing data of multiple days (from 01.05.2018 to 18.05.2018).

My dataframe "EperDtPanda" has this form:

```
                               ldr
timestamp                         
2018-05-01T00:00:03.454+02:00  972
2018-05-01T00:00:08.532+02:00  972
2018-05-01T00:00:13.462+02:00  973
2018-05-01T00:00:18.467+02:00  973
2018-05-01T00:00:23.472+02:00  968
2018-05-01T00:00:28.480+02:00  972
2018-05-01T00:00:33.487+02:00  973
2018-05-01T00:00:38.484+02:00  970
```

My index is of type: "timestamp"

Im plotting the whole period of data, using this code:

```
indicies = map(lambda t: np.datetime64(t), EperEtPanda.index)
newIndextValues = map(lambda v: v[0], EperEtPanda.values)

ts = pd.Series(newIndextValues, index=indicies)
series2 = ts.resample('H').mean()
plt.plot(series2.index, series2.values)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical');
```

And I get the plot attached, of 18 days of data.  [image: plot of whole period of 18 days]

Now I want to slice this plot into plots of 6h, and save the figures. 
Here is the code I used to slice the graph into 6h blocks:

```
startDate = '2018-05-01T00:00:00+02:00'
endDate = '2018-05-18T00:00:00+02:00'
blockLength = 6
i = 0

while (str_to_ts(startDate) < str_to_ts(endDate)):
    mask = (EperEtPanda.index >= str_to_ts(startDate)) & (EperEtPanda.index <= (str_to_ts(startDate) + timedelta(hours=blockLength)))
    EperDtPanda6h = EperDtPanda.loc[mask]
    slice6h = EperDtPanda6h.plot()
    slice6h.get_figure().savefig('figure6h' + i + '.png')
    startDate = str_to_ts(startDate) + timedelta(hours=blockLength)
    i += 1
```

str_to_ts is a function which converts stings into timestamp:

```
str_to_ts =  udf (lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+02:00"), TimestampType())
```

But it's not working..

Anyone has an idea how to get this done?

Comment: what is not working exactly? the function `str_to_ts`? you can do `startDate =  pd.to_datetime('2018-05-01T00:00:00+02:00')` to get a timestamp directly and no need of your str_to_ts anymore

Comment: it's not a pandas, it's just a sting that I am trying to convert..

Comment: yes it's just a string but you can use `pd.to_datetime` to create a timestamp  from the string outside of a dataframe :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
# to ensure timestamp type for indexes (not necessary if it's already the case for you)
EperEtPanda.index = pd.to_datetime(EperEtPanda.index)
# start and end date as timestamps
startDate = pd.to_datetime('2018-05-01T00:00:00+02:00')
endDate = pd.to_datetime('2018-05-18T00:00:00+02:00')
# create all the time between start and end with a freq of 6 hours
list_time = pd.date_range(startDate, endDate, freq='6H') 
# loop for with zip to have both start_time and end_time
i = 0
for start_time, end_time in zip(list_time[:-1], list_time[1:]):
    # select the 6h range with .loc and slice()
    EperDtPanda6h = EperDtPanda.loc[slice(start_time, end_time),'ldr']
    # plot and save
    EperDtPanda6h.plot().get_figure().savefig('figure6h' + i + '.png')
    i += 1
```

Hope it works for you